# Discord.js - ReferenceError: DiscordCollection is not defined

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, require, referenceerror

I was coding a bot using Discord.js, following Codelyon's code, and I am stuck with this error:

```
ReferenceError: DiscordCollection is not defined at Object.<anonymous>
```

```js
const {Client, Intents, DiscordAPIError, Collection} = require('discord.js');

const client = new Discord.Client({ intents: ["GUILDS", "GUILD_MESSAGES"] });

const prefix = '-';

const fs = require('fs');

client.commands = new DiscordCollection();

const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync(`./commands/`).filter(file => file.endsWith(`.js`));
for(const file of commandFiles){
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);

    client.commands.set(command.name,command);
}

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Ceeby Is Online');
})

client.on('message', message => {
    if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    if(command === 'ping'){
        client.commands.get('ping').execute(message, args);
    }
})
client.login('TOKEN')
```

Comment: DiscordCollection doesn't seems to be imported where as Collection is..

Comment: did you mean for this: `client.commands = new DiscordCollection();` to be this: `client.commands = new Collection()`? I dont see you using Collection anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 common methods to import and use a libraries such as [**discord.js**](https://discord.js.org): importing the whole module or object destructuring- examples of both below. You seem to be trying to do both at the same time, you destructor the object but use `Discord.Client` and `Discord.Collection` instead of just `Client` and `Collection`.

##### Whole Module

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
...
const client = new Discord.Client({ intents: ['GUILDS', 'GUILD_MESSAGES'] });
...
client.commands = new Discord.Collection();
```

##### Object Destructuring

```js
const { Client, Collection, DiscordAPIError } = require('discord.js');
...
const client = new Client({ intents: ['GUILDS', 'GUILD_MESSAGES'] });
...
client.commands = new Collection();
```

Comment: Thanks alot man, you really helped, ive been into this for like 3 hours now
should have signed up on Stackoverflow earlier XD

Comment: No worries, happy to help. Also we ask you don't comment `Compliments which do not add new information` as per [this support guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) and if you could instead either upvote or accept the answer :)